# android problem:Read file problem res/raw/img/img123.jpg

Tags: android

I'm beginner of android.
And I get a problem.
Can I get the file under the folder I create in res/raw?

For example: res/raw/img/img123.jpg

Can I get the id or use the file img123.jpg?

if yes,how can i do that?

Comment: I have a lot of file. So I want to create a folder to classify it.

Answer (score 1):

Please read this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Instead of accessing it as a `raw` resource, try creating a `res/drawable/img123.jpg` to easily access it using

```
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img123);
```

Comment: However, I have a lot of file. Also I want to create a folder to classify it. So can I create a folder under res/drawable/ , like res/drawable/0001/img123.jpg then get the file(img123.jpg)?
THANKS YOU~